# Mysqli 2 records being created with one insert

Tags: php, file-upload, mysqli, insert-into

I am using the following form to create a photo album, it submits the data to a processing script which then deals with the files and enters data into the database.

THIS IS THE SUBMIT FORM :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Create New Album</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>Create New Album</p>
    <form action="createnewalbumsubmit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">

        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo substr(md5(time() * rand()),0,10); ?>" name="albumid" id="albumid" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" name="datecreated" id="datecreated" />
      <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isalbum" id="isalbum" />

      <p>
        <label for="albumname">Album Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="albumname" id="albumname" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="albumthumbnail">Album Thumbnail Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="albumthumbnail" id="albumthumbnail" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
      </p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

THIS IS THE DATA PROCESSING SCRIPT, IT IS USING THE VEROT UPLOAD CLASS FOR DEALING WITH THE UPLOADED FILE AND THEN MYSQLI TO ADD DETAILS TO THE DATABASE :

```
    <?php include("connect.php"); ?>
    <?php
    // Posted Data
    if(isset($_POST['albumid'])){
        $albumid = $_POST['albumid'];};

        if(isset($_POST['datecreated'])){
        $datecreated = $_POST['datecreated'];};

        if(isset($_POST['isalbum'])){
        $isalbum = $_POST['isalbum'];};

        if(isset($_POST['albumname'])){
        $albumname = $_POST['albumname'];};
        //


        require_once 'uploadclass/class.upload.php';

        $file = new Upload($_FILES['albumthumbnail']);
    if ($file->uploaded) {
      // save uploaded image with a new name,
      // resized to 100px wide
      $albumthumbnail = substr(md5(time() * rand()),0,10);
      $file->file_new_name_body = $albumthumbnail;
      $file->image_resize = true;
      $file->image_convert = 'jpg';
      $file->image_x = 100;
      $file->image_ratio_y = true;
      $file->Process('albums/'.$albumid.'/thumbnail/');
      $filename = $file->file_dst_name;
      if ($file->processed) {
        echo 'image renamed, resized x=100
              and converted to jpg';
        $file->Clean();
      } else {
        echo 'error : ' . $file->error;
      }
    }

    mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO albums (`albumid`,`datecreated`,`isalbum`,`albumname`,`albumthumbnail`) VALUES ('$albumid','$datecreated','$isalbum','$albumname','$filename')");

    ?>
```

The problem I am having is that when I create a new record TWO records are being created in the database, one blank record with nothing at all in it and one valid record with all of the details of the added album in it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're not checking if the form is being posted. Each time you land on the page it will run:

```
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO albums (`albumid`,`datecreated`,`isalbum`,`albumname`,`albumthumbnail`) VALUES ('$albumid','$datecreated','$isalbum','$albumname','$filename')");
```

This is why you're getting a blank record. You need to surround your submit code with `if (!empty($_POST)) { }` as such:

```
<?php
include ("connect.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // Posted Data
    if (isset($_POST['albumid'])) {
        $albumid = $_POST['albumid'];
    };

    if (isset($_POST['datecreated'])) {
        $datecreated = $_POST['datecreated'];
    };

    if (isset($_POST['isalbum'])) {
        $isalbum = $_POST['isalbum'];
    };

    if (isset($_POST['albumname'])) {
        $albumname = $_POST['albumname'];
    };
    //

    require_once 'uploadclass/class.upload.php';

    $file = new Upload($_FILES['albumthumbnail']);
    if ($file -> uploaded) {
        // save uploaded image with a new name,
        // resized to 100px wide
        $albumthumbnail = substr(md5(time() * rand()), 0, 10);
        $file -> file_new_name_body = $albumthumbnail;
        $file -> image_resize = true;
        $file -> image_convert = 'jpg';
        $file -> image_x = 100;
        $file -> image_ratio_y = true;
        $file -> Process('albums/' . $albumid . '/thumbnail/');
        $filename = $file -> file_dst_name;
        if ($file -> processed) {
            echo 'image renamed, resized x=100
              and converted to jpg';
            $file -> Clean();
        } else {
            echo 'error : ' . $file -> error;
        }
    }

    mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO albums (`albumid`,`datecreated`,`isalbum`,`albumname`,`albumthumbnail`) VALUES ('$albumid','$datecreated','$isalbum','$albumname','$filename')");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that's sorted it now !.

Comment: Note that the recommended way to check if it was a POST request, is by checking it as such: if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') ...